# igraph Number of vertexs

Tags: c++, hash, igraph

I am trying to write some code that uses the igraph library from C,  I have never used it before.

In section 2 of the users manual it states

"The vertices in a graph are identified by an integer number between 0 and N-1, N is the number of vertices in the graph"

Naturally this being the real world my list of vertexts can start from any 32 bit  number may be non continuous.

Does the igraph library support any type of mapping function for converting non continuous range of keys with the values A to H(where A to H are any integers A< H)   to a  range of keys with a 0-n number range?

I am just wondering if I can use a C++ map function to map between the two ranges of numbers but I am worried as to what happens if I attempt to map between two keys that generate the same hash value.

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) can indeed be used, and it doesn't use hashes.

Comment: Thank you Joachim,  I will use that.